# How can use the setInterval() to change the text?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, timing

I've been working at this for quite some time now. I'm trying to create a simple timer that counts down. I've gotten the alert() to work, but unfortunately the textToChange does not change. I've reproduced a copy of my code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var timeLeft = 0;
    var changingTextElement;
    var changingText = new Array();
    var ctr = 0;

    function timeMsg(thing)
    {
    var length = thing.inputbox.value*1000;
    var t = setTimeout("alertMsg()",length);
    timeLeft = length/1000;
    initChangeText();
    }

    function alertMsg()
    {
    alert("Alert!");
    }

    function initChangeText(){
        changingTextElement = document.getElementById("textToChange");
        changingText[ctr] = changingTextElement.innerHTML;
        ctr++;
        while(timeLeft > 0){
            changingText[ctr] = timeLeft;
            timeLeft--;
            ctr++;
        }
        ctr = 0;    
        setInterval("changingText()",1000);
    }

    function changingText() {
        ctr++;
        if(ctr >= changingText.length){
            changingTextElement.innerHTML = 0;
        }
        else{
            changingTextElement.innerHTML = changingText[ctr];
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Could you also post your html so we can verify id's, elements etc?

Comment: There is not reason to create the `changingText` array (it can become potentially huge). You can compute the right value to display on the fly...

Comment: @Thomas: No, `changingTextElement` is defined in global scope at the top of the script block. If you add `var` it will not work in any way.

Comment: @Thomas - why, they are defined globally so only need to change is from a purist point and not from a functionality point of view

Answer (score 3):

You are using a `changingText` function and a `changingText` array ...

See the conflict ?

---

As additional info,

do not use strings as name functions in the `setInterval` method. Use a reference to the method directly

```
setInterval(changingText, 1000);
```

Comment: Took me too long to figure that one out. What a waste of a fiddle :(

Answer (score 1):

For a simple countdown timer, this code is too big. Basically, what you should be doing is:

- Set the number of seconds from which should be counted down
- Start a timer using `setInterval` which decrements the counter and displays it

That can be simple as:

```
var countFrom;
var timer;
function run_timer() {
    document.getElementById("textToChange").innerHTML = --countFrom;
    // !0 evaluates to true, if the counter reaches 0 (wait 0 seconds) ...
    if (!countFrom) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        alert("Timer finished!");
    }
}
function init_timer () {
    // stop previous timers if any
    clearInterval(timer);
    // start counting from 30 seconds
    countFrom = 30;
    timer = setInterval(run_timer, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your version in a fiddle. I changed the function name

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/jqeDv/