# jquery change div content on time interval

Tags: jquery, setinterval, timing

Have a look at this pic:
[image]
You can see a Quote block under the image slider (it's nivo slider if it's useful).
I have to change the sentence in the quote block every time the image changes.
I thoungh that was impossible, but just thinking a bit pheraphs I can set an interval with setInterval() to the quote block and set the time in a way that fit the slider time.

I don't really know how to do it I think I have to set an array of sentence that are display in html at a specific time...
Oh and I need a fade effect but I don't think it is a problem...

Thanks a lot in advace

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007311/how-can-use-the-setinterval-to-change-the-text?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I would think that you could achieve your goal with Nivo Slider's built in caption functionality. You can style the caption element as needed.

"*To add a caption to an image you simply need to add a title attribute to the image. To add an HTML Caption simply set the title attribute to the ID of a element that contains your caption (prefixed with a hash). Note that the HTML element that contains your caption must have the CSS class nivo-html-caption applied and must be outside of the slider div.*"

http://dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/#/documentation

If that doesn't suit, use an afterChange function to update your caption element:

```
$('#slider').nivoSlider({
    afterChange: function() {
        // Do your caption update here.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use the [Cycle Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) it sounds like exactly what you are looking for.The plugin provides a method called cycle which is invoked on a container element. Each child element of the container becomes a "slide". Options control how and when the slides are transitioned.

here is a sample [Demo](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/basic.html)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'fade' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
    });
});
```